# WaitForSeconds on C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait, seconds

Look at this simple code:

```
function Start()
{
    yield WaitForSeconds (4);
    Application.LoadLevel(1);
}
```

It works! I'm trying to make something similiar using C#, but the processor just ignore the WaitForSeconds. This is my code in C#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class openingC : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        executeWait(5);
        Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }

    void executeWait(float aux)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait(aux));
    }

    IEnumerator Wait(float seconds)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain to me why it's not working? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class openingC : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        executeWait(5);
        Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }

    void executeWait(float aux)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait(aux));
    }

    IEnumerator Wait(float seconds)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    }
}
```

First, the Start method runs, executeWait is called, the program jumps to the method. It finds the coroutine and starts running it until a yield is found or the end of the method. Yield returns to the program, the pointer goes back up to executeWait and finishes the method. The pointer goes back up to Start and calls for Application.LoadLevel.

You want to hang the LoadLevel call.

```
public class openingC : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Wait(5));
    }

    //You don't need executeWait

    IEnumerator Wait(float seconds)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
        Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Thread.Sleep(500); //500 millisecond waiting...
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I put in the start method and appears this: "The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You should add `System.Threading` to your project references.

Comment: Does not work, just crashes Unity. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Actually what I wanted was only the processor to wait a few seconds to read the next line of code, but this seems impossible, I can not find anywhere how to do. This Sleep looks like make all the codes stop run.

Comment: OP is using Unity3D which supports co-routines - a mechanism for simple deferred execution without blocking.  `Thread.Sleep()` would block the game

Comment: @Micky: Right, but you can use it like `Task.StartNew(YourMethod)` to prevent blocking your main or other threads in your application,don't you?

Comment: No, because Unity3D is limited to .NET 3.5.  `Task` is unsupported

Comment: ok,but to achieve this functionality, you can create a new thread and start it that supported in the all of .Net versions : `new Thread().Start()`

Comment: Yes that would work, but when making games, using threads for anything other than say audio or I/O; should generally be avoided, using thread pools or not.  Otherwise the net effect is an inconsistent frame rate as threads contend with each other; locking resources unexpectedly not to mention memory use is not free.  There are many ways to perform _deferred execution_ without using threads.  http://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Architecture-Jason-Gregory/dp/1568814135

Comment: Let's wrap this one up for good. There is no reason to use threads or other complex topic for something that is made easy by Unity. Coroutine is simple and provide a similar result to thread without all the issues (coroutine is not thread, at least not to the user). In this case, coroutine does the job easy and clean. No need to try and justify the use of thread, it is irrelevant here. You would consider threads for expensive computation like pathfinding, or maybe some complex networking connection. Not for some trivial actions like a timer.

Answer (score 0):

This should also be okay.

```
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
        Application.LoadLevel (1); 
    }
```

Comment: It is ok, at least it has been for long (maybe newer versions of Unity have removed the possibility to do so). Nonetheless, it should not be done this way according to Unity dev. There must be some internal reason for not using it, I don't know them. The downvote is unclear too.